# BuildWebCompiler fails in Azure Pipeline

Tags: sass, msbuild, azure-pipelines, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We are using the nuget package `BuildWebCompiler` to compile scss files in our blazor web assembly app. Locally in Visual Studio this works as expected, but in our azure build pipeline we get the following error:

```
  WebCompiler: Begin compiling compilerconfig.json
    Compiled wwwroot/app.css
    Minified wwwroot/app.min.css
    Compiled Pages/ErrorsPage.razor.css
    Compiled Shared/NavMenu.razor.css
    Compiled Shared/MainLayout.razor.css
    Compiled Components/ErrorComponent.razor.css
    Compiled Components/ErrorDetailComponent.razor.css
    Compiled Components/NameValueBaseComponent.razor.css
    Compiled Components/NavigationComponent.razor.css
    Compiled Components/StackframeComponent.razor.css
    Compiled Pages/ErrorEventPage.razor.css
    Compiled Components/FilterComponent.razor.css
    Minified Components/FilterComponent.razor.min.css
  WebCompiler: Done compiling compilerconfig.json
  {AppName}.Services.App -> D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\bin\release\net5.0\{AppName}.Services.App.dll
  {AppName}.Services.App (Blazor output) -> D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\bin\release\net5.0\wwwroot
  {AppName}.Services.Api -> D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.Api\bin\release\net5.0\{AppName}.Services.Api.dll
  {AppName}.Services.Api -> D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.Api\bin\release\net5.0\{AppName}.Services.Api.Views.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest" task failed unexpectedly. [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not find a part of the path 'D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\obj\release\net5.0\scopedcss\bundle\{AppName}.Services.App.styles.css'.) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:  ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\obj\release\net5.0\scopedcss\bundle\{AppName}.Services.App.styles.css'. [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.OpenRead(String path) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<GenerateAssetManifest>b__0(Int32 i) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int32 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018: --- End of stack trace from previous location --- [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int32 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Replica.Execute() [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskReplicator.Run[TState](ReplicatableUserAction`1 action, ParallelOptions options, Boolean stopOnFirstFailure) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018: --- End of stack trace from previous location --- [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ThrowSingleCancellationExceptionOrOtherException(ICollection exceptions, CancellationToken cancelToken, Exception otherException) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, Action`1 body) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.GenerateAssetManifest(Stream stream) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.Execute() [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
D:\core-1-2\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(140,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [D:\core-1-2\1\s\src\{AppName}.Services.App\{AppName}.Services.App.csproj]
```

Do you guys have any idea, whats wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that azure build system cannot find a part of your path.

First of all check if the variables are macro expanded. I think the problem should be there.

Then check the file path in your json definition file.

Comment: What do you mean with "macro expanded"?

Comment: {AppName} should be expanded

Comment: Oh that. I just removed the real project name out of the logs so there is nothing to expand ;)

Comment: I think the problem is in the json compiler configuration file